# Average of an uarray in python uncertainties

Tags: python, arrays, uncertainty

My problem:

I have an array of ufloats (e.g. an unarray) in pythons uncertainties package.
All values of the array got their own errors, and I need a funktion, that gives me the average of the array in respect to both, the error
I get when calculating the mean of the nominal values and the influence  the values errors have.

I have an uarray:

`2 +/- 1
3 +/- 2
4 +/- 3`

and need a funktion, that gives me an average value of the array.

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example of the result you would expect from that dataset?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Gaussian statistics, the uncertainties stem from Gaussian parent distributions. In such a case, it is standard to weight the measurements (nominal values) by the inverse variance. This application to the general weighted average gives,

$$ \frac{\sum_i w_i x_i}{\sum_i w_i} = \frac{\sum_i x_i/\sigma_i^2}{\sum_i 1/\sigma_i^2} $$.
[image]

One need only perform good 'ol error propagation on this to get an uncertainty of the weighted average as,

$$ \sqrt{\sum_i \frac{1}{1/\sum_i \sigma_i^2}} $$
[image]

I don't have an n-length formula to do this syntactically speaking on hand, but here's how one could get the weighted average and its uncertainty in a simple case:

```python
    a = un.ufloat(5, 2)
    b = un.ufloat(8, 4)
    wavg = un.ufloat((a.n/a.s**2 + b.n/b.s**2)/(1/a.s**2 + 1/b.s**2), 
                     np.sqrt(2/(1/a.s**2 + 1/b.s**2)))
    print(wavg)
    >>> 5.6+/-2.5298221281347035
```

As one would expect, the result tends more-so towards the value with the smaller uncertainty. This is good since a smaller uncertainty in a measurement implies that its associated nominal value is closer to the true value in the parent distribution than those with larger uncertainties.

Comment: Note that the above formula relies on the existence of real uncertainty values for all terms.  If the uncertainty is zero for a measurement (impossible!), the result will be undefined (due to division by zero).  Also, I'm very much unsure of what to make of "the uncertainty of the weighted average".  In many reference papers I have read, the uncertainty of averages *generally* relates to calculations involving the range of values present in the average (in this case (8-5)/2 = 1.5).  If we shrink down the uncertainties of a and b, we should not go below 1.5 as a overall uncertainty in the mean.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann I don't believe that uncertainty being the range of values is a standard let alone an appropriate use. It might vary across fields. A weighted average is just a mean, with the precision of measurements in mind. If you quote 9+-1 and 6+-4, I'm going to believe the true value of whatever it was you measured to be closer to 9. The weighted average reflects this. Just like with the measurements though, this mean should also have a margin. Error propagation is built on the idea of a deviation using calculus. I believe that's better formulated than a range.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't address the fundamental question of what happens when two measurements actually disagree.  If both claim to be relatively error-free, and their difference is larger than their error terms, what should happen?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you could calculate the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) divided by the length of the array:

```
from uncertainties import unumpy, ufloat
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([ufloat(2, 1), ufloat(3, 2), ufloat(4,3)])
print(sum(arr)/len(arr))
# 3.0+/-1.2
```

You can also define it like this:

```
arr1 = unumpy.uarray([2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])
print(sum(arr1)/len(arr1))
# 3.0+/-1.2
```

[`uncertainties`](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/numpy_guide.html) takes care of the rest.

Comment: I doubt thats it, if I use this on my real data, I get an error value of +/- 0.4 while the standard error of the mean of the nominal values is around 8.

Comment: You might have a different error distribution. This [article](https://newton.cx/~peter/2013/04/propagating-uncertainties-the-lazy-and-absurd-way/) might interest you.

Comment: The problem with this is you're getting the nominal value and uncertainty of the simple sum divided by the length of entries. See my answer (coming up).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a .csv file which stores variables in 'mean+/-sted' format, you could try the code below; it works for me.

```
from uncertainties import ufloat_fromstr
df=pd.read_csv('Z:\compare\SL2P_PAR.csv')
for i in range(len(df.uncertainty)):
df['mean'] = ufloat_fromstr(df['uncertainty'][I]).n
df['sted'] = ufloat_fromstr(df['uncertainty'][I]).s
```